# Determining identity of unknown compound with NMR data

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

[image: IR spec and C NMR]
[image: H NMR]
I have the following IR spec, C NMR and H NMR data. The boiling points determined for the unknown compound were 116.8 and 119.1°C (two trials). Given the possible compounds, the unknown can be one of:

```
3-methyl-2-butanol
1-butanol
3-pentanol
2-pentanol
2-methyl-1-butanol. (These are based on boiling point)
```

I have eliminated some of these choices based on the number of different types of carbons (4, as shown on C NMR) but am not sure where the H of the OH is indicated in H NMR. There is no singlet present among the 3 groups of peaks, so where would it be?

Answer (score 2):

Peaks of acidic protons in an NMR spectrum can change (in position, form and intensity) due to exchange with other volatile protons.

- A very fast exchange makes the peaks coalesce, you get one singlet between the two "original" (expected) chemical shifts, the exact position depends on the respective amount of both.
- A slower exchange, one "on the NMR timescale", broadens that peak considerably, typical case is residual water and a COH proton. The peak might in some cases be so broad it becomes invisible.
- Even slower, this peak splits into two, which become sharper and further removed from each other.
- A very slow exchange makes no change to the positions, but an exchange with deuterium (i.e. from the solvent) changes the relative intensity of the respective peaks over time.

Comment: Is the greatest possibility in this case then a slower exchange where peak is invisible? I did not do the experiment myself so I am unsure.

Comment: No, in case of a slow exchange, the proton would instead appear as a large residual solvent peak. But the chloroform peak at 7.2 is nice and small. I believe that there is an exchange with an approximately equivalent amount of residual water, happening with a rate of a hundred or a thousand Hertz, broading the peak so much it vanishes into the baseline. My best guess.

Answer (score 0):

The proton on O or N atoms can be acidic enough to exchange with the deuterium atoms of the NMR solvent, thus "hydrogen-bonding protons" are often absent from H NMR spectra, or may show up "[anywhere](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_interpret-NH_and-OH_peaks_in_proton_NMR_and_how_to_report_them_in_a_publication/amp)".

Comment: Alcohol protons don't exchange with CDCl3. (notice the peak at 7.1ppm). What can make them "vanish" is the exchange with residual water.

Comment: The chloroform peak would esp. be much larger if there was an exchange.